# PHP. How to explode •

Tags: php, explode

I have some text:

```
text,text • text.text • text:text
```

I need

```
array('text,text','text.text','text:text);
```

How do I explode •?
WORK!!! need:

```
            $txt =  html_entity_decode($txt);
            $textArray = explode("•",$txt);
            print_r($textArray);
```

Comment: What appears to be the problem, good sir? https://3v4l.org/MHaSl

Comment: This is just a stab into the dark, but the most likely problem is an ***encoding problem***. However "•" is encoded in `$txt` and in your source code's string literal `"•"` is not the same. Use `echo bin2hex("•"), bin2hex($txt)` to figure out the difference!

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
$str = "text,text • text.text • text:text";
$new_arr = explode ('•', $str);
```

Comment: @АндросенкоЄвгеній Well, since that certainly *do* work, you'll have to show us a concrete example that we can troubleshoot.

Comment: $textArray = explode("•",$txt);

Comment: Array ( [0] => 'text,text • text.text • text:text' )